# Костер - питоме чи запозичене слово?

Tags: іменники, росіянізм

Часто в Інтернеті натрапляю на слово **костер**. Зазирнула у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/koster), а там справді таке слово зафіксоване. Однак я впевнена, що таке слово є у [російський](https://slovar.cc/rus/ojegov/595320.html), тому задля підтвердження дивлюсь і туди.

Отож цікавить, чи, випадково, слово костер - не є саме запозиченням із російської?

Comment: Зазначу, що 1) слово позначене _діялектним_, 2) значіння ся ріжнять 3) вставити цітати з осїдків, для московської ще перекласти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Російсько-український словник](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53402/141576.html) подає український відповідник:

> **КОСТЁР**
>
> 1) багаття (-ття), (ум. багаттячко), огнище, огнисько, **костер (-тра), кострище**, (зап.) ватра, (тлеющий) жариво, (дымный) курище.

Зі статті у  [Етимологічному словнику](http://resource.history.org.ua/cgi-bin/eiu/history.exe?C21COM=S&I21DBN=ELIB&P21DBN=ELIB&S21FMT=elib_all&S21ALL=%28%3C.%3EAT%3D%20%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%3C.%3E%29&Z21ID=&S21SRW=nz&S21SRD=UP&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21CNR=20) можна зробити висновок, що це слово є спільним для слов'янських мов:

> [image: Blockquote]

2 значення цього слова (*стоколос житній*) також надає інформацію, що це слово спільнослов'янського походження, тому **костер** не є запозиченням з російської.